# google cast receiver returns unavailable anyway

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

i tried some googlecast samples(e.g [googlecast/CastHelloText-chrome](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-chrome))

but any samples its receiver returns "unavailable" on my custom-receiver.

- first, default application id in samples(e.g '794B7BBF' ) works good.no problems.
- registered receiver.html in samples on [Google Cast SDK Developer Console](https://cast.google.com/publish), and replace application id to published one, but any receivers found on sender.
- reboot chromecast, checked "Send this Chromecast's serial number when checking for updates." checkbox, reinitialized chromecast and registered serial number again but they were ineffective.

here are console logs on console of chrome developer tools when access receiver.html

```
 [  0.034s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Version: 2.0.0.0008 cast_receiver.js:18
Starting Receiver Manager receiver.html:46
 [  0.035s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Opening message bus websocket cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.036s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Opening the WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc cast_receiver.js:18
Receiver Manager started receiver.html:91
 [  2.062s] [goog.net.WebSocket] An error occurred: undefined cast_receiver.js:18
 [  2.062s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IpcChannel error cast_receiver.js:18
 [  2.063s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message cast_receiver.js:18
 [  2.064s] [goog.net.WebSocket] The WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc closed. cast_receiver.js:18
 [  2.064s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IpcChannel closed cast_receiver.js:18
 [  2.064s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message cast_receiver.js:18
 [  2.064s] [goog.net.WebSocket] The WebSocket disconnected unexpectedly: undefined cast_receiver.js:18
 [  2.064s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Seconds until next reconnect attempt: 1 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  3.068s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Opening the WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc cast_receiver.js:18
 [  5.076s] [goog.net.WebSocket] An error occurred: undefined cast_receiver.js:18
 [  5.076s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IpcChannel error cast_receiver.js:18
 [  5.076s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message cast_receiver.js:18
 [  5.077s] [goog.net.WebSocket] The WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc closed. cast_receiver.js:18
 [  5.077s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IpcChannel closed cast_receiver.js:18
 [  5.078s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message cast_receiver.js:18
 [  5.078s] [goog.net.WebSocket] The WebSocket disconnected unexpectedly: undefined cast_receiver.js:18
 [  5.079s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Seconds until next reconnect attempt: 2 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  7.080s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Opening the WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc cast_receiver.js:18
 [  9.083s] [goog.net.WebSocket] An error occurred: undefined cast_receiver.js:18
 [  9.084s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IpcChannel error cast_receiver.js:18
 [  9.084s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message cast_receiver.js:18
 [  9.084s] [goog.net.WebSocket] The WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc closed. cast_receiver.js:18
 [  9.084s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IpcChannel closed cast_receiver.js:18
 [  9.085s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message cast_receiver.js:18
 [  9.085s] [goog.net.WebSocket] The WebSocket disconnected unexpectedly: undefined cast_receiver.js:18
 [  9.085s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Seconds until next reconnect attempt: 4 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 13.087s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Opening the WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 15.091s] [goog.net.WebSocket] An error occurred: undefined cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 15.091s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IpcChannel error cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 15.091s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 15.091s] [goog.net.WebSocket] The WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc closed. cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 15.092s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IpcChannel closed cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 15.092s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 15.092s] [goog.net.WebSocket] The WebSocket disconnected unexpectedly: undefined cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 15.092s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Seconds until next reconnect attempt: 8 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 23.094s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Opening the WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 25.097s] [goog.net.WebSocket] An error occurred: undefined cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 25.098s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IpcChannel error cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 25.098s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 25.098s] [goog.net.WebSocket] The WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc closed. cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 25.099s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IpcChannel closed cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 25.099s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 25.099s] [goog.net.WebSocket] The WebSocket disconnected unexpectedly: undefined cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 25.099s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Seconds until next reconnect attempt: 16 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 41.675s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Opening the WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 43.679s] [goog.net.WebSocket] An error occurred: undefined cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 43.680s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IpcChannel error cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 43.680s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 43.682s] [goog.net.WebSocket] The WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc closed. cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 43.682s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IpcChannel closed cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 43.682s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 43.682s] [goog.net.WebSocket] The WebSocket disconnected unexpectedly: undefined cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 43.682s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Seconds until next reconnect attempt: 32 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 76.675s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Opening the WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 78.679s] [goog.net.WebSocket] An error occurred: undefined cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 78.680s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IpcChannel error cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 78.680s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 78.680s] [goog.net.WebSocket] The WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc closed. cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 78.681s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IpcChannel closed cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 78.681s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 78.681s] [goog.net.WebSocket] The WebSocket disconnected unexpectedly: undefined cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 78.681s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Seconds until next reconnect attempt: 60 cast_receiver.js:18
```

are there any idea?
i am looking forward to your reply. 
thanks.

Comment: double check your serial number, it is sometimes hard to read it and easy to confuse a "0" with a "O", etc.

Comment: Also, as a test, see if you can open a debug chrome session to your chromecast device on port 9222.

Comment: @AliNaddaf thanks for replying. i tried them a while ago.In the first place, i can't open a debug chrome sessions on port 9222. i tried check a serial number again and again and again...

Comment: if you cannot access port 9222, then you're device is not registered for your app. The common issues are: (1) incorrect serial number, (2) forgot to check the checkbox during set up of chromecast

Comment: oh, you were right. i got incorrect s/n.now, i can access port 9222. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, cannot access port 9222 even inputed correct serial number, after reboot from chromecast desktop app.
To make sure reboot device, i got to reboot by reconnect chromecast manually.